# Postgres Subquery Limit based on Condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `events` that contains a `type` and a `resourceId`.
I am looking to find `resources` that contain *all* of a certain `event.type`

The query I have so far is:

```sql
SELECT
    "resourceId",
    case
        WHEN array_agg(DISTINCT "type") @> '{0,1}'::INTEGER[] THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS "containsEvents"
FROM
    events
GROUP BY
    "resourceId"
--  I WANT TO DO THIS vvv
-- HAVING "containsEvents" = 1
LIMIT 10;
```

If I'm not mistaken, MySQL allows `HAVING` in aliases.
Is there a way around this in Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the logic you want?

```
SELECT "resourceId",
FROM events
GROUP BY "resourceId"
HAVING array_agg(DISTINCT "type") @> '{0,1}'::INTEGER[]
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: It is indeed. I could have sworn I tried this, but I must've done the `agg` in `WHERE` and not `HAVING`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want resources that have both types `0` and `1`. I don' think you need array aggregation. I would phrase this as:

```
select "resourceId"
from events
where "type" in (0, 1)
group by "resourceId"
having count(*) = 2
```

This assumes no duplicate `("resourceId", "type")`. If not, you can just change `count(*) = 2` to `count(distinct "type") = 2` in the `having` clause.

If you want resources that have both 0 and 1 types *and no other* type, then:

```
select "resourceId"
from events
group by "resourceId"
having 
    count(*) filter(where type in (1, 2)) = 2
    -- or count(distinct type) filter(where type in (1, 2)) = 2
    and count(*) filter(where type not in (1, 2)) = 0
```